# Any way to add new line at end of multiple text files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am merging (concatenating) many text files into one,
but I have the problem that they don't have a new line at the end of the text.

Is there any way to append a new line to all files using Windows command or batch file?

I am using `cmd.exe` of Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this as a batch file

```
del merged.txt

for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~fI >> merged.tmp
    echo ------------- >> merged.tmp
    type "%%I" >> merged.tmp
    echo. >> merged.tmp
    echo. >> merged.tmp
)

ren merged.tmp merged.txt
```

This way you don't have to specify the names but all the files must be in the same folder.

The `echo %%~fI` echo the full path name, for other options you can consult

```
help for
```

Other than that, if the result is not exactly as you want, probaby all you need is just changing what are `echo`-ed

Comment: all worked well , thanks buddy. ANy way to add name of the file in the merged file

Comment: I don't know how exactly you want it, but I think my edited answer should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

You can concatentate files using COPY

For example, files: data1.txt and data2.txt can be combined by:

```
copy data1.txt + data2.txt dataFull.txt
```

and the result will be in dataFull.txt.  If you leave off the destination it will all be in the first listed file.

To insure a newline the easiest, although not most elegant method would be to create a file, newline.txt, which is simply a blank line and include it after each file:

```
copy data1.txt + newline.txt + data2.txt dataFull.txt
```

It would be fairly straight forward to include this addition in a looping structure.